# groups.ngroups query degrade after migration to docValues

Tags: solr

I am planning to use the docValues feature of Solr. I have added "docValues= true" parameter to a few fields in my schema on which there is heavy faceting and grouping query involved. While I noticed a considerable improvement in faceting queries. I didnt get any improvements in grouping query and instead places where i used "group.ngroups=true" in my query there was around 3-4 times degradation in performance.

Any know issues or possible workarounds for this case

Comment: Please, provide some details about your index. E.g. Number of documents, number(at least approximately) of distinct values in docValues field, total size on disk, etc.
Query example will also be quite helpful. (Is it _just_ a group.ngroups query? Or there is also some complicated search logic besides grouping?)

Comment: The details of the index is as follows Number of docs - 42 lakhs,total size 8.6 gb, distinct values of doc field are approx 12 lakhs. Query is a simple ngroups query q=*:*&group=true&group.field=authId&group.ngroups=true&rows=0